# Issue when including DirectXMath.h

Tags: c++, directx-11

I am writing a simple game using DirectX 11 and have recently had issues when trying to include DirectXMath to one of the .h files. When I include it and try compiling, I get an error C3861 saying that 'assert' : identifier not found. It points me to several lines inside DirectXMath that make use of assert and of other files inside DirectXMath.

I have never had issues with using DirectXMath before and have been struggling to solve this problem. Any help would be deeply appreciated. I am posting below my includes in the WinMain file that is triggering the error (sorry for the bad format, could not copy and paste the code).

include Windows.h
include tchar.h
include d3d11.h
include directxmath.h

If I comment the directxmath.h I don't get any errors. The interesting part is that I use directxmath in other files in the same solution (different project but same solution) and it all compiles fine.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do any of your includes do something along the lines of `#undef assert`?

Comment: DirectXMath has a ``#include <assert.h>`` to ensure the assert macro si defined before it is used extensively in the app. Do you have a "assert.h" in your project?

Comment: I do have assert in my project and it is working fine. I don't undefined it at any point. I am thinking it is something that I am doing wrong in the set up of this specific project as other projects in the same solution compile this library fine with similar includes and defines. Is there something that one can do on the project set up that would make the assert.h file found but the lowercase assert func not defined?

Comment: Do you have a filename called ``assert.h`` in your project that is not the official MSVC CRT header? You can try using the compiler command-line option /P on a file in your project and look at the resulting output file which shows the fully pre-processed file. Then search for assert in there. Also make sure if you are using precompiled headers that you always have the PCH header ``#include`` first in all your files.

Comment: This did the trick. I had a file called assert.h in a different project that was in the include path and I think it was being used before the regular assert.h file. I renamed my file in the other project and all is working fine. Thanks so much for the help!